# Reduce string length in c, where is the fault?

Tags: c, string

i have two different filenames, which are defined in a header file:

1: "physio_sensor_readout.csv"
2: "statethresh_configuration.csv"

they are initialised by

```
char* filename;
```

and later

```
filename = FILENAMEINAMACRO; which is the corresponding filename above
```

Later, filename is passed to another function which alters the ending:

```
filename[strnlen(filename, FILENAME_LENGTH) - 4] = '\0';
```

This should remove the ending .csv and i strncat a new one afterwards.
FILENAME_LENGTH is 60, so enough space.

It works if i pass "statetresh_...."(even the strncat afterwards) but not with "physio_se.....". This throws a segment fault

```
strnlen(filename,FILENAME_LENGTH - 4)
```

returns 21 in case 1 and 25 in case 2. this is the correct position of the dot, where i want to put the terminating null.

Is this a problem with char* and should i initialise filename with char filename[60]?

Regards and thank you

edit:

your suggestions solved the problem. thanks!

Comment: It would seem that `FILENAMEINAMACRO` is probably a quoted string, and therefore that you're trying to modify a string literal, which is undefined behavior.  Change `filename` to an array, and use `strcpy` (or `strncpy`, which isn't just a save version of `strcpy`) to put it in.

Comment: It's probably what they said, but just in case, `strnlen(filename, FILENAME_LENGTH) - 4` is not the same as `strnlen(filename,FILENAME_LENGTH - 4)`

Comment: What is the exact issue here? Isn't strnlen function returning the correct values?

Answer (score 2):

I *think* you declare `FILENAMEINAMACRO` as [string literal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal) [Without more code I cannot be sure about it].

string literals might be saved on read only memory - so you might not be able to change them.

In any way, trying to change string literals results in undefined behavior.

You might want to make a copy of `FILENAMEINAMACRO` and work on it using [`strcpy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/)

Answer (score 2):

It is not safe to modify the contents of a character literal. Something like this:

```
char *filename = "yes";
filename[2] = 'p'; // change to "yep"
```

is undefined behavior, and can cause disastrous results, because `filename` can be pointing to memory that can't be modified. Instead, try something like this:

```
char filename[] = "yes";
filename[2] = 'p'; // change to "yep"
```

which will allocate a new array `filename` and initialize its contents with `"yes"`.

Answer (score 0):

You are appear to be pointing your char* pointer `filename` at a character constant. I assume you have defined `#define FILENAMEINAMACRO "physio_sensor_readout.csv"`. This makes your assignment `filename = "physio_sensor_readout.csv";`. You then use the filename pointer to modify the string constant. Here is a more suitable sequence:

```
char filename[256];   // choose a size that is suitably large
...
strcpy(filename, FILENAMEINAMACRO);  // also look at strncpy for safer copying
...
... manipulate the content of filename as you wish ...
```

Because you have made a copy of the string literal, modifying it is safe (as long as you stay within the bounds of the declared size of `filename` -- which includes keeping any terminating null also within the bounds.

You should be careful using the `char filename[] = "..."` form. It allocates enough space for the string literal you give it, but if later you copying some other string literal into that space you must be certain that the second literal is no longer than the first. A safer practice is to dimension the space to be large enough that you're certain your code will never attempt to use any more than what you have dimensioned. If you accept input from outside the program (or from other person's code), you should check the length of what you are accepting before trying to copy it into the space you have dimensioned. Any use of space beyond the dimensioned size is likely to cause issues that can be hard to diagnose. In the example above, you must make all efforts to ensure you never use more space (including the terminating nul char) than 256 chars (because filename is dimensioned at 200).